# Testing subscription trial periods with Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm implementing a Client / Server integration of Stripe and I want to simulate the trial end of a user.

According to the docs https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing#trials :

> There’s a quick solution here: create a new subscription with a
>   trial_end value only a few minutes in the future.

So here is how I create my Stripe Session :

```
$session_configuration = [
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'customer' => $stripeIdCustomer,
    'subscription_data' => [
        'items' => [[
        'plan' => $planId,
        ]],
        'trial_end'=>  time() + 60 * 1
    ],
    'success_url' => $success_url,
    'cancel_url' => $cancel_url,
];

$session = Session::create($session_configuration);
```

But then, I got an InvalidRequestException :

> The `trial_end` date has to be at least **2 days** in the future.

Whereas I'm in testing mode, what should I do ? Also, what are the relevant WebHooks to watch in this case ?

Comment: Have you tried creating the subscription, *then* modifying it? This restriction appears to only apply to a Checkout session.

Answer (score 1):

According to the api, any date less than 48 hours away is invalid.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-trial_end

The way that we got around this issue was by creating this function. Forgive the javascript, but I'm sure you can make it work.

```
    const includeTrialIfElligible = (trialEndsAtUtc) => {
      if (!trialEndsAtUtc || isPast(trialEndsAtUtc)) {
        return
      }
      const daysTillTrialEnd = differenceInCalendarDays(trialEndsAtUtc, new Date())

      // ex. if the trial period is ending in 1 hour, the user will 
      // get one trial period day and will get charged the "next day" or in one hour.
      if (daysTillTrialEnd <= 2) {
        return {
          trial_period_days: daysTillTrialEnd,
        }
      }
     
      return {
        trial_end: trialEndsAtUtc,
      }
    }
```

We then spread the response in subscription data and achieved the behavior that we wanted.

```
   const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create(
      {
        mode: 'subscription',
        ...
        subscription_data: {
          application_fee_percent: DEFAULT_PLATFORM_FEE_PERCENTAGE,
          ...includeTrialIfElligible(trialEndsAtUtc),
        },
        ...
    )
```

Comment: Hello  Ben and welcome to SO. Unfortunatly this an old question, since then I did a lot of different things that's why I'm not able to validate your answer right now. If some other user validate it, I will be happy to accept it.